# Delete a file in a folder using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code (thanks to very friendly people here at SO for their help):

```
 timeout /t 15 /nobreak >NUL

 findstr /i /v /c:"Registered Owner" %HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\systeminfo1.txt >%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\systeminfo.txt
```

This waits 15 seconds and then outputs a sysinfo log into a .txt file (systeminfo1.txt), and then re-writes it with the **Registered Owner** field removed in a new .txt file (systeminfo.txt). That works beautifully, and I am happy with it.

Now I want to go ahead and have the systeminfo1.txt deleted **after** systeminfo.txt is created and written to.

How would I go about this as far as code goes? I was reading up on various ways to do this command-wise, but I'm really not in the mood to accidentally delete my entire drive if I make a careless mistake.

Comment: Well, give it a try. When you try to delete a file, you cannot easily accidentally delete the entire drive. Worst case, you delete the wrong file, but since there are no wildcards, folders, recursive command and other such things involved, I think you can only destroy the wrong file by forgetting the `1` in the file name.

Comment: @GolezTrol Exactly, though doing it through C++ is completely different (my own experience- I accidentally deleted an entire project once, because I messed the code up). Batch files CANNOT delete the whole system drive, since Windows will not allow it to do so, unless the batch file is run with Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
timeout /t 15 /nobreak >NUL
findstr /i /v /c:"Registered Owner" "%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\systeminfo1.txt" > "%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\systeminfo.txt"

del "%UserProfile%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\systeminfo1.txt"
```

The `del` removes the file.

Note that the above code requires **administrator privileges**. If you don't want to, or can't use administrator privileges, then ensure that you have permissions to write/read/delete from `%UserProfile%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\`.

For Linux (if you have a desire to perform the same task on Linux in the future), use the `rm` command.

Comment: You seemed to have missed the first % in the %HomeDrive% variable. Not a problem, I've added it! However, I'm getting an error - The network path was not found. Is this due to the variables I am using in the file path? Unfortunately, I believe they are necessary in my case as this is a script for not only my system.

Comment: @Patrick I've looked around the 'net, and it seems that Windows can't find the drive, which is strange since it can find it in your original code.

Comment: Better add double quotes to allow the use of long filename/path elements.  Your del command is looking in the root directory too.

Comment: @foxidrive the `cd` switches the root directory to the folder first, or am I wrong? If you could edit my answer for the double quotes, that would be great, since I only know basic batch 'programming' (if you could consider it programming, which you might not).

Comment: The \filename.ext refers to a root directory file.  I edited your code to add the quotes and also to specify the full path to the file, as that is a usual way to do it.

Comment: @Patrick Try it now, it should now work. foxidrive Thank you for editing the code to the correct format :-).

Comment: Unfortunately my friends, no dice. 'The network path was not found'.

Comment: @Patrick are you able to `cd "%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\FOLDERNAME\`?

Comment: Just tested it with a clean elevated CMD, worked just fine. Do note that I am also running my batch as admin, so permissions shouldn't be a problem (unless I am missing something).

Comment: @Patrick Perhaps some part of your file path refers to a Windows default directory, such as `Users`.

Comment: @Patrick I updated the answer to accommodate for this requirement. If you feel that your question has been answered, then please mark my answer as the accepted answer, by clicking on the tick just below the voting buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean my batch works now, I meant that using CD in a clean CMD works and it has no issue getting to the directory there, but it still doesn't work in my batch. Using your updated post, I still get a network path error.

Comment: @Patrick I've updated the answer with another fix. Please tell me whether or not this works.

Comment: @Patrick Note that I changed `%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%` with `%UserProfile%`, which apparently is the proper way of obtaining the user's home directory.

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! That worked with zero hiccups. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Patrick Glad to hear that :-). If you found my answer useful and it answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Already done my friend, thank you again. I have one last question now that we're on the topic of %USERPROFILE% (cannot believe I forgot about it)! Do you suggest I also go ahead and change    %HomeDrive%\%HomePath% to    %USERPROFILE% as well for the code above the delete code line? I suppose in the end it all works the same, really.

Comment: @Patrick I suppose it might make the batch file's commands consistent, but as you said, it works all the same.